# Unable to start debugging.Program path 'abc.dylib' is missing or invalid|LLDB failed with message: Command 'target-attach'. Attach to processs failed:

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to use the debugger in vs code. I have problems below launch.json and getting errors at lldb attach time. How we can fix this issue?

> error "Unable to start debugging. Program path 'abc.dylib' is missing or invalid. | LLDB failed with message: Command 'target-attach'. Attach to processs failed: "

```
{"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [




    {
        "name": "(lldb) Attach",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "attach",
        "targetArchitecture": "x64",
        "program": "abc.dylib",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
        "MIMode": "lldb",
        "logging": {
            "engineLogging": true,
            "trace": true,
            "traceResponse": true
        },
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false
    }
]
    }
```

Comment: So I assume your program is written in Java, and you are using cppdbg as your debugger which is for c++. So, perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: I am using JNI, and wish to debug JAVA and C code simultaneity